# Unable to creating Eos account with nodejs using eosjs library

Tags: eosjs, eosio-code, accounts

I have no idea where am i making mistake? please help.

```
const express = require('express');
const path= require('path');
const app =express();


const { Api, JsonRpc, RpcError } = require('eosjs');
const { JsSignatureProvider } = require('eosjs/dist/eosjs-jssig');
const fetch = require('node-fetch');   
const defaultPrivateKey = "exsisting account private key"; // bob
const signatureProvider = new JsSignatureProvider([defaultPrivateKey]);

const rpc = new JsonRpc('http://jungle2.cryptolions.io:80', { fetch });

const api = new Api({ rpc, signatureProvider, textDecoder: new TextDecoder(), textEncoder: new TextEncoder() });

//Body parser Middleware
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended:false}));      

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.send('hello world')

  })


//
app.post('/', (req,res) => {
  // res.send(req.body.new_account_name);              
  var existingaccount = 'microfinanc1'
  var mynewaccount=req.body.new_account_name;
 var  pubkey=req.body.publickey;
  console.log('Is it working');
  console.log(pubkey);
  console.log(newaccount);


   result (async ()=> {

    await api.transact({
      actions: [{
        account:'eosio'  ,
        name: 'newaccount',
        authorization: [{
          actor: existingaccount,
          permission: 'active',
        }],
        data: {
          creator: existingaccount,
          name: mynewaccount,
          owner: {
            threshold: 1,
            keys: [{
              key: pubkey,
              weight: 1
            }],
            accounts: [],
            waits: []
          },
          active: {
            threshold: 1,
            keys: [{
              key: pubkey,
              weight: 1
            }],
            accounts: [],
            waits: []
          },
        },
      },
      {
        account: 'eosio',
        name: 'buyrambytes',
        authorization: [{
          actor: existingaccount,
          permission: 'active',
        }],
        data: {
          payer: existingaccount,
          receiver: mynewaccount,
          bytes: 5000,
        },
      },
      {
        account: 'eosio',
        name: 'delegatebw',
        authorization: [{
          actor: existingaccount,
          permission: 'active',
        }],
        data: {
          from: existingaccount,
          receiver: mynewaccount,
          stake_net_quantity: '1.0000 EOS',
          stake_cpu_quantity: '1.0000 EOS',
          transfer: false,
        }
      }]
    }, {
      blocksBehind: 3,
      expireSeconds: 30,
    }).then(function (result) {
      console.log("here??");
  console.log(result);
  })

  // .catch(function (error) {
  // if (error) {
  // console.log(error);
  // }
  // }) 

  })
  result();
});

const port = process.env.port || 5000;
app.listen(port ,()=> console.log(`server got started on port ${port} `));
```

Error

```
ReferenceError: newaccount is not defined
    at app.post (/home/guru/nodejs/express js/index.js:48:15)
```

Comment: What error you get ?

Comment: I have updated the question with what error im getting please have a look @AbdulManan

Comment: where is newaccount defined

Comment: I have not defined it any where,but wherever in action new account name is asked,have i given mynewaccount string there and sending its value from postman, and im getting the value which im sending from post man, its not coming null i have checked it

Comment: there is a problem with the data you send from postman try console.log(req.body) and see what it console.
Also check it with static value does the code works if you pass static data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have

```
console.log(newaccount)
```

which is not defined anywhere as a variable. This is a js typo instead of EOS.

Replace it with

```
console.log(mynewaccount)
```

Comment: I did it already, thank you for looking into